# File transfer over a serial port using Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, file-transfer, serial-port

I am looking for a way to transfer a file over from my Windows 8 computer to a [PandaBoard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PandaBoard) (has OMAP Ubuntu on it) using a serial cable.

The solution should work in general for any ARM board, so for that reason I am using the serial port. However I am unable to transfer over a file.

If I'm not mistaken SCP and PuTTY don't allow the transfer of a file over a serial port. Or I'm trying it in a wrong way. I have also tried HyperTerminal on Windows 8, but I keep having time-outs when using the file transfer for whatever protocol I select (XModem, Zmodem, etc.). I have the right specifications for serial port communication as I am able to use PuTTY to access the device and communicate with it.

Any suggestions? The best solution would be one that works for Ubuntu/Linux as well.

Comment: I am looking for same - I have PuTTY and can connect to see the other side, and I have pscp - and I just don't have an IP connection per se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a Linux based solution, then sending a file is as easy as running

```
cat [filename] > /dev/ttyS0
```

and receiving a file is as easy as

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 > [filename]
```

But if you're on Windows it's not so easy.  I would look and try to find a version of HyperTerminal (which used to come with WinXP, but they quit distributing it in the install *is sad*).

Comment: Warning: This approach (cat) tends to be less reliable than other approaches that do error correction.  Even when things work well, I've found that serial connections tend to have errors sometimes.  This might be okay for transferring a small bit of data, like an executable file that can do better file transfers, but I wouldn't use it much.  The question is tagged Windows 8.  Offhand, I would probably recommend SyncTerm or PuTTY, namely due to problems with HyperTerm (known terminal emulation shortcomings, and I don't know that the was-free HyperTerm is licensed for newer Operating systems).

Comment: This is indeed the approach I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

For serial communications, like XModem/ZModem, I'd start with just basic communication.  Can you get into a terminal program, and type on one end, and see the other end?  If not, you may have issues that cannot be resolved with software: [OpenBSD FAQ on Serial Connections](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq7.html#SerCon) states, "we offer one hint: just because the ends plug in doesn't mean it will work."  So start by verifying that hardware works okay.  If so, then also verify the basic communications settings: communication at 2400 or 9600 might be more prone to work with many hardware than 115200.  8N1 is a very common setting, 7E1 a bit less so, but such settings must match.

Whenever I've used SCP, it's been using TCP/IP, which means that an IP address must be assigned to both sides.  That is a totally different communication design than trying to use raw serial communications like ZModem.  Using IP will probably be easier once you've got IP working, although getting to the point of having IP working might be a bit more challenging overall, so ZModem may be an excellent choice.

I typically avoid XModem; some XModems don't even transfer the right number of bytes (but round up to a half-kilobyte), and don't transmit the filename.  However, if you do use XModem (or YModem, but especially XModem), there are a number of variations, so you need to make sure you're using the same one.  ZModem is typically more compatible with other ZModem implementations.

Comment: My question is specific for serial communication, using any other communication is out of the question. And I am sure the hardware works as I can use puTTY to connect and go through the files & folders etc. I just want to know how it would be possible to get a file over that cable. I also have the right settings so that is not a problem either.

Comment: In theory, if you can communicate, then you can successfully transfer a file.  That's general theory.  In practice, the specific task that you're seeking to do definitely can be done.  There are a number of potential hurdles, and even different possible software solutions (which you can begin to see by the various pieces of advice given by the different answers).  If the solution you are trying provides troubles, keep asking questions; maybe try a different solution; definitely don't give up on the grounds of it being impossible to work, because it definitely can work.